# Android: How to list all the files in a directory in to an array?

Tags: android, arrays, file, android-file

I have a variable "directorypath". It has the path to a directory in sd card.

```
Ex: "sdcard/images/scenes"
```

Now, I want to list all the files in the "directorypath" and want an Array to store all the file names in it.

```
Ex: Array[0]= Filename1, Array[1]= Filename2 Etc...
```

I tried something like `Array[] myArray = directorypath.listfile();` but didn't work..! 
Can anyone give me the code or at least help me? Much appreciated.

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? and what type is the "directorypath" variable?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it. By didn't work, I meant, I am getting junck values in the Array. something like 'jLoF01548' etc.. the same for all the items in that array.  directorypath is a String variable.

Comment: The String class has no listfile() method so either the program isn't compiling with some exception, or directorypath is a different variable type. By the way your question is purely a Java question. There's nothing specific about Android necessary to answer this question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think the problem you are facing is related to the external storage directory file path. Don't use whole path as variable if you can access with environment.

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/images/scenes";
```

Also, you can use the API listfiles() with file object and it will work. For eg ::

```
File f = new File(path);        
File file[] = f.listFiles();
```

Answer (score 9):

Try the following code which may help you

```
List<File> getListFiles(File parentDir) {
    ArrayList<File> inFiles = new ArrayList<File>();
    File[] files = parentDir.listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            inFiles.addAll(getListFiles(file));
        } else {
                inFiles.add(file);
        }
    }
    return inFiles;
}
```

This will return you list of files under the directory you specified.
From the File object in list.. you will get all information about files you required.

Comment: Thank you for the code but.. File[] files = parentDir.listFiles(); gives error 'Cannot resolve listFiles(); I am using Android Studio.

Comment: Check [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html) .. File class has the method listFiles().  check your imports.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
File externalStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File folder = new File(externalStorageDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + "/FilePath");
File file[] = folder.listFiles();
if (file.length != 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
        //here populate your list
    }
} else {
    //no file available
}
```

Comment: I know this may be old, but I'm trying this line for my application. As of right now. I just have a button, and i press it to tell me if i have any files in my directory. Now when i press it, the app crashes and ceases to work. I've narrowed it down to the second line of this code you wrote. can you tell me if there is a way to check if line 2 is setup? like a isset method?

Answer (score 0):

According to your error message "Cannot resolve listFiles()", you are trying to call a method on a [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) object, when you actually want to be calling that on a [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html) object.

Create a new File object,

```
String parentDirectory = "path/to/files";
File dirFileObj = new File(parentDirectory);
File[] files = dirFileObj.listFiles();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was indeed calling a function for improper data type. i.e., listfiles() won't work on String type variable..!!

SO, I created a File type variable and a File[] array to pass the list of files..! 
This solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

its very simple Just two lines of code

```
 File mListofFiles = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory.getAbsolutePath()+"/",childpath:Foldername);
 File f = new File(mListofFiles.toString());        
 File file[] = f.listFiles();
```